# How could I get which app user use to capture photos in Android

Tags: android, capture

Is there has a way to know which app(packageName or label) user use to capture,when I call capture intent

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

for example: com.google.camera

Answer (score 1):

Photos taken by the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE are not registered in the MediaStore automatically on all devices.

The official Android guide gives that example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive But that does not work either on all devices.

The only reliable method I am aware of consists in saving the path to the picture in a local variable. Beware that your app may get killed while in background (while the camera app is running), so you must save the path during onSaveInstanceState.

Edit after comment:

Create a temporary file name where the photo will be stored when starting the intent.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
fileName = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

fileName is a String, a field of your activity. You must save it that way:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
 super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
 bundle.putString("fileName", fileName);
}
```

and recover it in onCreate():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 if (savedInstanceState != null)
  fileName = savedInstanceState.getString("fileName");
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name")  // package name, e.g : com.google.camera
startActivity(intent)
```

You can open another application this way

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the answer only if there are 1 such app or the user selected the default app for this intent.

For obtain list of apps which support this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

So if this list contains only 1 app then you will have the required ResolveInfo.
For obtain app which was selected as default by the user:

```
 ResolveInfo defaultInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

This can be null if nothing selected.
If you have ResolveInfo then you can obtain the packageName and app name:

```
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
String appName = resolveInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
```

Comment: This way can't know which app user select to use if there is multiplie capturue apps. I want to know which app user use after capture

Comment: @yefeng This only possible in your own app if you create your custom app selector.
Otherwise you only have a captured photo, you can take a look on exif information in the photo, but not sure that this contains such information for every app.